# How to migrate from Guice to Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

Code to be migrated to a different codebase (which uses spring):

```
@Named
public class A {
   ....
}

public class B {
   private final A a;

   @Inject
   public B (A a) {
     ...
   }
   
   ....
}
```

I know two ways. Do both work? Is there any difference?

Option 1:

```
@Component (can I label this as a @Bean also?)
public class A {
   ....
}


public class B {
   @Autowired
   private final A a;

}
```

Option 2:

```
public class A {
  ...
}

public class B {
   private final A a;

   public B (A a) {
     ...
   }
}

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
   @Bean
   public A a() {
      new A();
   }
}
```

With option 2, do I need to do anything else like `@Autowiring` the `BeanConfig` in class B?

I am just starting to learn DI frameworks and this is bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

**@Component**

`@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component. You can use `@Component` across the application to mark the beans as Spring's managed components. `@Service` and `@Repository` are special cases of @Component. They are technically the same but you can use them for the different purposes.

**@Bean**

You can declare beans using the `@Bean` annotation in a configuration class. Configuration classes can contain bean definition methods annotated with `@Bean`

Here are the differences which might help you to evaluate your choices between `@Component` and `@Bean`:

- `@Component` is used to auto-detect and auto-configure beans using classpath scanning. `@Bean` is used to explicitly declare a single bean, rather than letting Spring do it automatically.
- `@Component` is a class level annotation whereas `@Bean` is a method level annotation and name of the method serves as the bean name.
- `@Component` need not to be used with the @Configuration annotation where as `@Bean` annotation has to be used within the class which is annotated with `@Configuration`.

Here is an article [Migration Guide from Guice to Spring](https://sgitario.github.io/migration-guide-guice-to-spring-di/) which might interest you.

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer my question regarding option 1 and option 2.